# Watermark all pdfs in folder with the file's name

Tags: command-line, pdf

I have a bunch of pdf files in a folder. I would like to watermark all of them. The watermak should be the name of the file itself. How?

I'm using ubuntu 18.04LTS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Create a script `gedit /home/user/folderwithpdfs/pdfstamp.sh`, which will generate watermark.pdf file with shortened filename's text inside as a watermark:

  ```
  #!/bin/bash
  text=${1?missing text to show}
  # Restricts string to 15 symbols from start, without extension and folder's path
  mtext=$(echo ${text:0:15} | sed 's/.pdf//' | sed -e 's,.*/,,') 
  angle=45 # in degrees counterclockwise from horizontal
  grey=0.75 # 0 is black 1 is white

  ps2pdf - - <<!
  %!PS
  /cm { 28.4 mul } bind def
  /draft-Bigfont /Helvetica-Bold findfont 72 scalefont def
  /draft-copy {
          gsave initgraphics $grey setgray
          5 cm 10 cm moveto
          $angle rotate
          draft-Bigfont setfont
          ($mtext) show grestore
   } def
  draft-copy showpage
  !
  ```
- Place it to folder with pdf files
- Run the next command inside the folder with pdf files, which will create watermark.pdf file each time, apply it to current file and output it to the new file:

  ```
  for f in ./*.pdf 
    do ./pdfstamp.sh "$f" > watermark.pdf
    pdftk "$f" stamp watermark.pdf output "$f.pdf"
  done
  ```

  The command will create filename.pdf.pdf files with watermark of file names but without extension and with 15 symbols length.

  [Script](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/295642/341457) mostly created by @meuh.

  Result:

  [image]

The next variant of the command will place watermark to the background, so it could look like transparent:

```
for f in ./*.pdf; do ./pdfstamp.sh "$f" > watermark.pdf && pdftk "$f" background watermark.pdf output "$f.pdf"; done
```

[image]

But this method has a downside: this watermark could be covered over by images.